# Pegar nome dos times em tabelas diferentes!

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia pessoal, mais uma vez venho pedir uma ajuda.

Tenho 3 tabelas no BD para exibir nome dos times, local e a competição, trazendo os resultados com JOIN esta funcionando, porem não estou conseguindo mostrar o nome dos dois times no resultado.

```
SELECT * FROM tabela JOIN times ON id_times = mandante_tabela JOIN locais ON id_locais = local_tabela
```

Preciso que que me traga ( Time mandante - Time Visitante - Local do Jogo )

Segue o exemplo rodando http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74e90e/1

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabela` (
  `id_tabela` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `mandante_tabela` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `visitante_tabela` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `data_tabela` date NOT NULL,
  `hora_tabela` time NOT NULL,
  `local_tabela` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `placar_mandante_tabela` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `placar_visitante_tabela` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ativa_tabela` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `tabela`
--

INSERT INTO `tabela` (`id_tabela`, `mandante_tabela`, `visitante_tabela`, `data_tabela`, `hora_tabela`, `local_tabela`, `placar_mandante_tabela`, `placar_visitante_tabela`, `ativa_tabela`) VALUES
(8, 11, 9, '2016-07-13', '14:30:00', 8, 0, 0, 0),
(9, 9, 8, '2016-08-12', '11:30:00', 10, 0, 0, 0);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tabela`
--
ALTER TABLE `tabela`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_tabela` (`id_tabela`);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `locais` (
  `id_locais` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nome_locais` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ativa_locais` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `locais`
--

INSERT INTO `locais` (`id_locais`, `nome_locais`, `ativa_locais`) VALUES
(8, 'Mineirão', 0),
(9, 'Independência ', 0),
(10, 'Ipatinga', 0);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `times` (
  `id_times` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nome_times` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ativa_times` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `times`
--

INSERT INTO `times` (`id_times`, `nome_times`, `ativa_times`) VALUES
(8, 'Riachinho', 0),
(9, 'Cruzeiro', 0),
(10, 'América', 0),
(11, 'Atlético', 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isso Marcos Paulo:

```
SELECT locais.nome_locais as  Local_do_Jogo,
(SELECT times.nome_times FROM times where times.id_times = tabela.mandante_tabela) as mandante,
(SELECT times.nome_times FROM times where times.id_times = tabela.visitante_tabela) as visitante
FROM tabela 
INNER JOIN locais ON locais.id_locais = tabela.local_tabela
```

Comment: Perfeito, Subselects, sempre esqueço deste recurso, hehehe, obrigado Ricardo, vou adaptar para o que preciso aqui!!